# Using HttpClient to upload files to ServiceStack server

Tags: servicestack, httpclient

I can't use the ServiceStack Client libraries and I've chosen to use the HttpClient PCL library instead. I can do all my Rest calls (and other json calls) without a problem, but I'm now stucked with uploading files.

A snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(restRequest.Method, restRequest.GetResourceUri(BaseUrl));  
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    byte[] data;
    bool success = CxFileStorage.TryReadBinaryFile(file, out data);
    if (success)
    {
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) ,
        };
        content.Add(byteContent);
    }
}
message.Content = content;
```

Problem is now that I get a null reference exception (status 500) when posting. I doesn't get into the service. I see the call in the filterrequest, but that's it.

So I'm wondering what I do wrong and how I can pinpoint what is going wrong. How can I catch the correct error on the ServiceStack layer?